# determine all (x,y) of the line Normal to an Ellipse

Tags: calculus, derivatives, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Hi everyone I have a question that requires me to determine the (x,y) coordinates of all points that intersects the x-axis on this ellipse when the normal line has a slope of  -4, and I'm curious to know if I am doing this correctly, if so is my work correct and is there a way to check if it is?. Thank you all very much in advance.

Given Function:
$$ \frac {(x^2)}{16} + \frac{(y^2)} {36}  = 1$$

I understand I take the derivative of the function implicitly or explicitly first, respectively they are:

$$y'=\frac{-9x} {{4y}}$$

$$y=\frac{-3x} {2\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$

First the implicit derivation and setting it equal to $-4$

$$-4 =\frac{-9x} {{4y}} $$

Then solving for $x$ and inputting the expression back into the original function

$$y = \frac{9x} {{16}} $$

$$\frac{x^2}{16} + {(\frac{9x}{16})^2\over{36}} = 1$$

$$\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{81x^2}{256} \cdot \frac{1}{36} = 1$$

$$\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{9x^2}{1024} = 1$$

$$\frac{73x^2}{1024}=1$$

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{1024}{73}}$$

$$ x=3.745 $$

Inputting the value of $x$ into the original function, solving for $y$

$$\frac{(3.745)^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{36} = 1$$

$$y=\sqrt{1-0.8767\cdot{36}}$$

$$y=2.106$$

therefore the coordinates are $$(3.745,2.1067)$$

Now for the explicit derivation and setting it equal to $-4$

$$-4=\frac{-3x} {2\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$

solving for x

$$-4\cdot{2}=\frac{-3x}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$

$$(-8)^2 = \frac{9x^2}{16-2x^2}$$

$$(64)(16-2x^2)=9x^2$$

$$1024-64x^2 = 9x^2$$

$$-73x^2=-1024$$
$$x=\sqrt\frac{1024}{73}$$
$$x=3.745$$

Inputting the value of $x$ into the original function

$$\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{36} = 1$$
$$\frac{3.745^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{36}=1$$ 
$$y=\sqrt{1-0.876}\cdot{36}$$
$$y=2.106$$

Therefore the coordinates are $$(3.745,2.106)$$

Comment: In the first equation you are using the variable $y$ to mean two entirely different things. Also, if the normal line has slope $-4$ then the slope of the tangent line will be the negative reciprocal of $-4$, namely, $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: What do you mean by points "intersecting" the $x$-axis? Are you looking for points on the ellipse where the normal line has slope $-4$ or are you looking for the equations of the tangent lines to the ellipse at those two points?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the two points of the ellipse where the slope of the normal lines equal $-4$ as well as the equations of the two lines tangent to the ellipse at those two points, then proceed as follows:

As you correctly deduce, $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{9x}{4y}$$

Therefore $$-\dfrac{9x}{4y}=\dfrac{1}{4}$$

at the points in question, so they lie on the line $$y=-9x$$

Substituting into the equation of the ellipse yields the two points

$$ \left(\pm\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{37}},\mp\dfrac{36}{\sqrt{37}}\right)$$

Using the point slope equation of a line, one obtains the equations tangent to the ellipse at those two points:

$$ y=\dfrac{1}{4}x\mp\sqrt{37}$$

respectively.

[image: Normal to an ellipse plus tangent lines]

Comment: @TonyK Thanks, using GeoGebra.

Answer (score 0):

**Obs**: I'm assuming you want to know which points int the ellipse have a normal line with slope $-4$

You seem to be confusing the *normal line* with the *tangent line*. You have the equation $$ \frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{36}=1\Rightarrow y=\pm \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{16-x^2}$$
So taking the derivative, we have two situations:
$$y'=\mp \frac{3x}{2\sqrt{16-x^2}}$$
Now, here is where you got confused. The derivative give us the slope of the tangent line at the given point. So, as the tangent line is *orthogonal* to the normal line, we have:
$$ m_n \cdot y' = -1 \Rightarrow m_n = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{16-x^2}}{3x}$$
Now, all you have to do is solve $m_n =-4$. That yields two equations:$$2\sqrt{16-x^2}\pm3x=0$$. The rest is up to you. You only have to input the result in the original function $y(x)$.